# ReferenceError: ... is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, funções, onclick

Olá, estou tendo um problema com o JavaScript que estou usando, vou colocar o exemplo prático que estou utilizando, na head do meu HTML tenho 3 aberturas de tag  diferentes. segue:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
    addDropDown(map);
  }
  function addDropDown(map) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown-holder');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(dropdown);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<script src="bundle.js">
var stringAtual = "";
  function insereMarca(){
    stringAtual = stringAtual + ":" + value;
    var funcoes = require('./funcoes')(value);
    alert(funcoes);
  }
</script>
```

Os dois primeiros são utilizados para a API do Google Maps e o ultimo é para fazer chamar o Node.js(bundle.js é o Browserify para utilizar o require).
No HTML eu chamo "insereMarca" com um onClick básico

```
<div class="dropdown-item" id="dropd" onclick='insereMarca()'>CLICK ME</div>
```

Porém este não funciona, gostaria de saber o porque,visto que a API do Google segue funcionando, o HTML aceita só um script na head ou algo do gênero?

Desde já agradeço :)

ps. se eu unir os dois scripts a API para de funcionar

ps2. quando clico no dropdown o console do navegador mostra "ReferenceError: insereMarca is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

Quando usas o atributo `src` no na tag `<script>` o conteúdo da tag é ignorado. Ou seja ter `<script src="bundle.js">` e ao mesmo tempo JavaScript dentro da tag é incompativel. Usa uma tag para cada:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var stringAtual = "";
function insereMarca(){
    stringAtual = stringAtual + ":" + value;
    var funcoes = require('./funcoes')(value);
    alert(funcoes);
}
</script>
```