# Javascript - Erro: x is not defined

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Boa noite galera,

Estou enfrentando uma dificuldade que, sinceramente, não achei solução até o momento.

Criei uma collapsed sidebar onde o arquivo javascript foi adicionado antes da tag **< /body>** da página que carrega a sidebar, porém o javascript aparece no source da web quando eu inspeciono mas a function não é carregada, aparece o erro: ***toggleSidebar is not defined***.

Daí eu peguei o mesmo código, fui até o codepen.io e funcionou normalmente.

Meu código completo com CSS e JS no CODEPEN: [Collapsed Sidebar](https://codepen.io/norsvold/pen/RwWVYxJ)

**

### HTML:

**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e943c11967.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Main Stylesheets -->
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<div id="adminSidebar" class="adminSidebar" onmouseover="toggleSidebar()" onmouseout="toggleSidebar()">
    <a href="#"><span><i class="material-icons">info</i><span class="icon-text">about</span></a><br>
    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">spa</i><span class="icon-text"></span>services</a></span>
    </a><br>
    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">monetization_on</i><span
            class="icon-text"></span>clients</span></a><br>
    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">email</i><span class="icon-text"></span>contact<span></a>
 </div>

 <div id="mainContent">
    <h2>Open/Collapse Sidebar on Hover</h2>
 </div>

 <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Obs.: Já tentei colocar o arquivo js abaixo do title lá no , porém não funcionou também.

Obs.²: Achei um post com o mesmo título ([ReferenceError: ... is not defined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142179/referenceerror-is-not-defined)) mas o problema é diferente, logo, não me ajudou.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: *"onde o arquivo javascript foi adicionado antes da tag < /body>"* não se adiciona arquivo no body, e sim no head

Comment: Como não? O lugar mais adequado para um arquivo JS é no fim do body, para ser carregado apenas após o HTML ser exibido...

Comment: ah, após o body ok, não tinha notado o /body, era mais fácil ter escrito "após o body" na pergunta ;)
mas cuidado com *"O lugar mais adequado para um arquivo JS é no fim do body"*, isso de o lugar mais adequado não é verdade, scripts que precisam ser executados **para que o body esteja pronto** não devem ficar ai, mas essa é outra coisa

Comment: de qualquer forma, testou colocar o script no head para ver se muda o comportamento?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Tentei sim, sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Executei o código, inclusive por meio de um app no celular, o que possivelmente está causando erro é o caminho indicado para o arquivo Javascript, tem que confirmar se o arquivo main.js está dentro da pasta js.

Comment: Pior que está mano, está dentro de public/js e foi esse o caminho especificado....

Comment: Quando eu acesso o console log na web e efetuo o hover do sidebar ele identifica, logo, acredito que o caminho esteja correto mas dai ele dá Error toggleSidebar not defined

Comment: Mas no código que publicou aqui está no caminho js/main.js por isso acho que está errado, quando roda no codepen, ele já coloca o caminho do arquivo JS e CSS automaticamente